# Can I use the same dev database for Azure AppFabric Workflows, as well as "regular" WF4.0 workflows?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric, azure-appfabric

I'm exploring the [.NET 4.0 Update 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/04/18/microsoft-net-framework-4-platform-update-1.aspx) features and installed the Azure Appfabric SDK and also Workflow Foundation Samples.

I'm mostly interested in testing the new State Machine, correlation, persistance, ASP.NET MVC, and Azure + MVC in this example.

Should I use a separate database for my Azure Appfabric work, and traditional ASP MVC Workflow work?  Can I use the same one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database schema AppFabric uses is a super set of the normal persistence schema. So it could  work but there is a good change AppFabric will get confused. My recommendation is to use separate databases if at all possible.